# How to make android lollipop notification dismissable on lockscreen?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

On lollipop, If the user has a pin set then some notifications aren't able to be swiped away. they act like a persistent notification when attempting to be dismissed.

Some apps notifications are able to be swiped away on the lockscreen without unlocking.

I have only tested this with hide sensitive notification content, does a flag set change this ability?

How do I achieve this?

Comment: How are you building your notification? Can you include that code?

Comment: I haven't made a notification for my app yet as I want to use this as part of my notification but wasn't sure how easy it would be. apps that i've noticed this with are sms messages/email being undismissable and AIDE reminder is dismissable.

Answer (score 2):

This flag makes your notification stick:
Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

If you leave it out you can remove it. If you put it in, it sticks.

FYI: How I make my notifications:

```
    //These are parameters for setting up the tag in the tray
private static final String NOTIFICATION_ID_TAG="notificationID";
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID=123456;

public void createNotification() {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity_Host.class);
    intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID_TAG, NOTIFICATION_ID);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Service Running")
            .setContentText("The service is running").setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    //THIS FLAG MAKES THE NOTIFICATION STICK = YOU CAN'T SWIPE IT AWAY... IF YOU LEAVE IT OUT YOU CAN REMOVE THE NOTIFICATION
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);

}
```

This is how you can remove the notification from within the code:

```
        //Erase the notification that we set up when the service started
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

As you see, you can get the notification from the NotificationManager by the NOTIFICATION_ID you used to make it. This is just a number i made up.

Comment: If this answers your question, you might want to set it "answered". Otherwise you might want to comment on what's not clear!